# Draw a curve like sinewave using plotly.js

Tags: javascript, plotly.js

I'm trying to plot a curve across discrete point with given (x, y) value. The red line is what I can plot at the moment. Actually, the blue line is what I want to plot. How can I plot a curve instead of the straight line across given points?

[image]

I've tried to change the mode of the trace but it is useless.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow You simply haven't got enough points. You have 9 (visible) points on your red line, whereas you'd need at least a hundred to get anywhere near the blue one. Also, we cannot help you to debug your code if you don't show it to us. Please [edit] the question with a [mre], i.e. your code.

Comment: @Adriaan, these points is actually what I have. My target is to draw a curve across those points using suitable Algorithm

Comment: We'll need (a lot) more information in that case. Do you e.g. already know you'll get a sine wave? If you have just those nine points and nothing more, you'll have difficulty plotting anything more smooth based on purely your data. Also see the [Nyquist sampling criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyquist%E2%80%93Shannon_sampling_theorem), which is relevant in your case, since you appear to have (severely) undersampled data.

Comment: @Adriaan I know it is a sine wave. Based on Nyquist sampling criterion, the sampling rate is 8 kHz with frequency from 0.3 to 3.4 kHz. In my case is 3.4 kHz. It means that there is only an avarage of 2.35 periods in a period of the sine wave. As in my image, there are 9 sample in 3 periods.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.